# could not find plexydesk in dash after installing in ubuntu 12.10 how do i run it?

Tags: software-installation

i tried many times with these codes

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:plexydesk/plexydesk-dailybuild
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plexydesk
```

and successfully its installed. but when i typed plexydesk in  my Dash 
i could not find any thing. its not showing. how can i get it to work? if any one know please describe me. do i need to re-install it again with another way? or is there any way to open and run the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might visit [this page](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/plexydesk-ubuntu-linux-widgets). It says you need to add the PPA `ppa:plexydesk/plexydesk-dailybuild` to your Software Sources, update and then install ‘plexydesk’ from the Ubuntu Software Centre.